# Métodos na Entidade em arquitetura DDD

Tags: c#, ddd

Poderiam me ajudar em uma dúvida. Em arquitetura DDD quais tipos de métodos devo por em minha Entidade e quais devo por em meu Serviço de Domínio? Sei que em minha entidade devo por no mínimo o método de validação da própria entidade, e quando ao restante dos métodos devo obrigatoriamente por no serviço de domínio ou existe outros tipos de métodos que posso por na entidade? Obrigado.

Comment: Uma entidade publica todos os seus comportamentos. Aos serviços cabem os comportamentos que não pertencem naturalmente a nenhuma entidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias abordagems e escolhas que variam com domínios específicos, mas no DDD a idéia é tornar a entidade o mais "rica" possível.

Isso quer dizer que se você puder colocar o método em uma entidade específica, e manter seus atributos privados, esta é a melhor escolha. Ou seja, abuse da Orientação a Objetos (encapsulamento e coesão).

Um serviços de domínio só deveria ser criado quando a regra de negócio não "cabe" em uma entidade só, tendo que utilizar de Propriedades publicas de duas ou mais entidades.

Comment: Olá Fernando, obrigado pela resposta, mas no caso dos métodos CRUD eles deveriam ficar na entidade? Para mim é um pouco confuso o que por na própria entidade, o que por no serviço de domínio, o que por no serviço de aplicação ou o serviço de aplicação é uma cópia do serviço de domínio? Para um novato isso fica um pouco confuso.

Comment: Sobre Percistência de Dados, o DDD aconselha o uso de Repositorios, que são classes especializadas para isso, deixando suas entidades de domínio livres desta responsabilidade.  Mas novamente isso fica muito subjetivo sem um contexto maior. (do que se trata o projeto, se vai usar o Entity Framework, etc)

Comment: A entidade não deve ser o mais rica possível, mas apenas tão rica quanto necessário, perseguindo muito mais a pobreza do que a riqueza; o mesmo valendo para qualquer tipo de artefato no sistema (queremos manter tudo tão simples quanto possível). Além disso, um serviço não executa a regra que "não cabe em uma entidade só" mas sim a regra que não pertença naturalmente a nenhuma entidade. Não se trata de enfiar tudo que der na entidade até não aguentar mais, mas sim de encontrar o responsável ideal por cada regra de negócio.

Comment: Isso é mais um "jogo de palavras", não vejo minha respostar dizendo o contrário do que você disse. Mas acho que naturalmente tendemos a criar nossos sistemas de uma forma muito procedural, e quanto mais flexível somos em criar serviços, mais procedural o sistema ficará.

Answer (score -2):

Pelos meus estudos de Evans e Vernom, e pela prática que venho adotando, os métodos devem ser postos em entidades (sejam raizes de agregado ou não) visando permitir a alteração de seu estado interno. Aqui enfatizo que é sempre recomendável que os nomes de tais métodos expressem o motivo ou razão da alteração no estado de um objeto. Falo isso porque por vezes vejo métodos como Pedido.AlterarStatus(Status.Fechado) quando seria melhor e faria mais sentido para negócio algo do tipo Pedido.Fechar().
Quanto a serviços de domínio, eles são indicados em casos onde, por exemplo, uma logica de negócio requer que sejam alterados mais de uma raiz de agregado (sejam da mesma classe ou não). Nesse caso (se fizer sentido para o negócio!!!), você precisará orquestrar a alteração desses objetos em um contexto de transação.
Vale lembrar que se a orquestração entre objetos não envolve regras de negócio, você pode realizar tal orquestração em um serviço de aplicação ou diretamente em uma camada de Handler, acionada via um mediador - nosso famoso padrao Command.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).